# Passing values from child window to parent in tkinter (python3): unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a python GUI with tkinter that, among other things, will work with values entered into pop-up 'child' window. Here is a very stripped down version of the GUI:

```py
from minimalChild import Child
import tkinter as tk

class exGui(tk.Tk):

    def update(self):
        self.amount = Child(self)
        print(self.amount)

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.grid()

        self.amount = 0
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="pay", command=self.update).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=frame.quit).grid(row=0, column=1)

def main():
    exGui().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and a minimal version of the Child class:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Child(tk.Toplevel):

    def submitFunction(self):
        amount = 2
        self.parent.amount= amount
        self.destroy()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.grid()

        submit = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Submit', command = self.submitFunction).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Evidently I am not understanding the flow in the update method, since `print(self.amount)` does not give the expected value '2'. Rather, it gives some float number that appears before I click the 'submit' button and is different every time I run the code. Is there some way to tell the main window to wait for Child to return a value? Also, can anyone explain what that decimal number is? I would have expected the print statement to at least return 0?

I have looked at this thread [Pass user input from child to parent window python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927296/pass-user-input-from-child-to-parent-window-python-tkinter) and still could not understand how to solve the problem.

Any help, criticism or pointers to references would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Thanks for the clear concise question.

When you assign Child to self.amount in your update method you print it out immediately.  On my console I get .!Child printed.  The method completes it doesn't wait for any action in Child.  It creates the window, prints the value of amount and then waits for user interaction with either of the windows.  In the update method you have set amount to be the object created by Child().

What you wrote probably does set parent.amount to 2 but it does it after you printed the result.

I've added a result label to your main window, which initially shows 0.  Submitting from Child sets it to 2.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Child(tk.Toplevel):

    def submitFunction(self):
        amount = 2
        self.parent.amount.set(str( amount)) # Set parent amount.
        self.destroy()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.grid()

        submit = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Submit', command = self.submitFunction).grid(row=0, column=0)

class exGui(tk.Tk):

    def update(self):
        self.kid = Child(self)
        print(self.amount, self.kid, self.amount.get())

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.grid()
        self.amount = tk.StringVar() # Make amount a StringVar
        self.amount.set('0') # Set it to 0
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="pay", command=self.update).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=frame.quit).grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.result = tk.Label(frame, textvariable = self.amount).grid(row=0, column=2) # Add a result label.
# This is linked to the self.amount StringVar.

def main():
    exGui().mainloop()
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Yes, your answer and example code was clear and helpful, thank you!